# How do I put a slide counter in nivo slider?

Tags: javascript, jquery, nivo-slider

I am building a website with nivo slider image gallery. Its a briliant slider, but i need a slider counter like 1/6 (slide 1 of 6). I searched in the support page and google but all what i have found was the same question unanswered...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use one of the nivo [callback options](http://nivo.dev7studios.com/#usage).

```
$('#slider').nivoSlider({
    afterChange: function(){
        $('#counter').text( $('.controlNav .active').text() );
    }
});
```

After each slide change it will take the text contents of the active nav control and use it to populate your counter. If you would like to provide a more specific context I could offer an explicit solution.